# docker compose Error: In file './docker-compose.yml', the service name True must be a quoted string, i.e. 'True'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos7

Here is my [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/827).
I read the similar question in stackoverflow, but still don't know why.
Will it related to centOS ( I found a [link](https://forum.seafile.com/t/error-in-file-docker-compose-yml-the-service-name-true-must-be-a-quoted-string-i-e-true/9655), and he is using centOS too)

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're asking here.  Neither here nor the GitHub issue you link to includes the actual `docker-compose.yml` file; and even so it seems like you have a pretty clear error with a suggestion.

Comment: I am learning docker compose today, but as I followed the steps in docs, it didn't work as expect, but report an error in my terminal.
The error message is in question title, which tells me that `docker-compose.yml` file has some errors. But my `docker-compose.yml` file is copied from those docs I mentioned in issue. So I don't know the reason the error happens.
I checked the `docker-compose.yml` file serveral time, found nothing wrong.